# How to replace strings with a specific value to another string in a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
AID   Name      Country
1     XX-USA    FL, USA
2     YY        USA-USA
3     YY-USA    UK
```

I want to replace instances in `Country` only that include the string 'USA' for instance into 'USA' alone.

So the result would be

```
AID   Name      Country
1     XX-USA    USA
2     YY        USA
3     YY-USA    UK
```

I tried `df.replace` but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I don't know what am i doing "wrong", but it works just fine for me:

```
In [83]: fn = r'D:\download\countries.csv'

In [84]: Alldf = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=',')

In [85]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 10

In [86]: Alldf
Out[86]:
            aid             name   country
0      79533B41   john sarracino       USA
1      7E0706FD   ben wiedermann       USA
2      7B33445B     rishit sheth       USA
3      7F4CE233       yijun zhao       USA
4      262087DD     roni khardon       USA
...         ...              ...       ...
13387  7C62148F    marcel kutsch       USA
13388  7F42F95A     john z zhang    Canada
13389  7DAF3AED     chris sanden    Canada
13390  00375817  michal laclavik  Slovakia
13391  13D9B371     marek ciglan  Slovakia

[13392 rows x 3 columns]

In [87]: Alldf.loc[Alldf.country.str.contains('USA'), 'country'] = 'USA'

In [88]: Alldf.country.value_counts()
Out[88]:
USA                    6150
China                  1426
Singapore               517
UK                      448
Germany                 398
                       ...
New York Unversity        1
Berkeley and QUT          1
CA 94022                  1
WA 98109                  1
and Google research       1
Name: country, Length: 377, dtype: int64

In [89]: Alldf.loc[Alldf.country.str.contains('USA'), 'country'].unique()
Out[89]: array(['USA'], dtype=object)
```

---

**Old answer:**

```
In [74]: d
Out[74]:
   AID    Name  Country
0    1  XX-USA  FL, USA
1    2      YY  USA-USA
2    3  YY-USA       UK

In [75]: d.loc[d.Country.str.contains('USA'), 'Country'] = 'USA'

In [76]: d
Out[76]:
   AID    Name Country
0    1  XX-USA     USA
1    2      YY     USA
2    3  YY-USA      UK
```

Comment: i got this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Comment: @BKS, `d` - in my answer is a DataFrame object... You are trying to to call `d.loc[...]` where `d` is a string object

Comment: mine is also a dataframe.

Comment: @BKS, either your error message is wrong or you are calling `d.loc[]`, where `d` is a string object ;-) What is the output of `print(type(d))`?

Comment: Here are my two lines of code: `Alldf = pd.read_csv('../data/countries.csv', sep='\t')`
    `Alldf = Alldf.loc[Alldf.country.str.contains('USA'), 'country'] = 'USA'`... It reads from a csv into a dataframe then I do what you suggested.

Comment: @BKS, what is the output of `print(type(Alldf), Alldf.columns.tolist())`?

Comment: `(<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, ['aid', 'name', 'country'])`

Comment: I use python 2.7 could that be it?

Comment: @BKS, no, it shouldn't depend on Python version

Comment: @BKS, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'` says clearly that you are calling `.loc[...]` for a string object... Do you have anything between those two lines of code you've posted in the comment?

Comment: no those two line are ALL the code i'm running. `AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-28a8bf1ae41a> in <module>()
      1 Alldf = pd.read_csv('../data/countries.csv', sep='\t')
      2 print(type(Alldf), Alldf.columns.tolist())
----> 3 Alldf = Alldf.loc[Alldf.country.str.contains('USA'), 'country'] = 'USA'

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Comment: even when I try `.iloc[...]` i still get the same error

Comment: @BKS, can you upload your `countries.csv` somewhere?

Comment: @BKS, did you see UPDATE section in my answer?

Comment: for some reason it works now! not sure what the difference was exactly. Thanks!